# Existence of a probability measure under which a subset of $[0,1]$ cannot be approximated by a Borel set

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

Is there some probability measure, $p$, on $\left(\left[0,1\right],2^{\left[0,1\right]}\right)$ relative to which some $D\subseteq\left[0,1\right]$ cannot be approximated by a Borel set, i.e. if $E$ is any Borel set $E\in\mathfrak{B}\left(\left[0,1\right]\right)$, $p\left(D\Delta E\right)>0$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Assuming there is a real valued measurable cardinal, this will be true of any total extension $p$ of Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$. This is because the measure algebra of any such extension is not separable. This fact is due to Gitik and Shelah.

If you want to directly construct such a measure, you can start with a model of $GCH$ with a measurable cardinal $\kappa$ and add $\kappa$ random reals. In the resulting model (due to Solovay), $2^{\omega} = \kappa$ and one can easily construct a total extension $p$ of Lebesgue measure such that the measure algebra of $p$ is isomorphic to random forcing for adding $(2^{\omega})^{+}$ many random reals.

Edit: I think the following also holds: Let $p$ be any total measure on $[0, 1]$ that vanishes on singletons. Then there is a set $X$ such that $p(X \cap E) = p(X^c \cap E) = p(E)/2$ for every Borel set $E$. This follows from the result of Gitik Shelah mentioned above combined with a theorem of Maharam.

Comment: Thank you. Sounds impressive, but i can't mark your reply as the correct answer because i don't have the knowledge to verify your answer and you haven't cited specific references for the results you mentioned so i can check it.

Comment: Here's the reference: M. Gitik, S. Shelah: Forcings with ideals and simple forcing notions, Israel J Math 68 (1989) 129-160. The following survey article of Fremlin is also useful: D. Fremlin, Real-valued-measurable cardinals, Proc. 1991 Bar-Ilan Conference (ed. H. Judah), Amer. Math. Soc., 1993 (Israel Mathematical Conference Proceedings 6), 151-304.

Comment: Thanks. Even with the reference, your answer is still too difficult for me at the present time, but i hope to be able to check it sometime in the future.

Comment: I'm confused about your reference to GCH.  Without loss of generality we can assume $p$ vanishes on all singletons.  If CH holds (much less GCH) then the countably additive measure $p$ is $\mathfrak{c}$-additive, which means $\mathfrak{c}$ is real-valued measurable.  But [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal#Real-valued_measurable) says that Banach and Kuratowski proved that under CH, $\mathfrak{c}$ is not real-valued measurable.  Am I missing something?

Comment: GCH only holds in V. In the random real extension, continuum is real valued measurable so CH must fail. In retrospect, I don't see why I assumed GCH in V. We can start with any model with a measurable $\kappa$ and add $\kappa$ random reals. Anyway, this doesn't seem relevant to the question which was about the Maharam type of the measure algebra of a total atomless measure, which is always strictly above the least rvm by Gitik Shelah theorem.